# Failed to linked symbol in .so file while the symbol exists

Tags: unix, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I want to install lxml module in my unix system, and it doesn't work. the problem is failed to reference symbol:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Sep 12 2010, 18:46:30) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ld.so.1: isapython2.6: fatal: relocation error: file lxml/etree.so: symbol __xmlStructuredErrorContext: referenced symbol not found
```

however, the output of `ldd` command is:

```
$ ldd lxml/etree.so
        libxslt.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1
        libexslt.so.0 =>         /usr/lib/libexslt.so.0
        libxml2.so.2 =>  /lib/libxml2.so.2
        libz.so.1 =>     /lib/libz.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        libpython2.6.so.1.0 =>   /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/sfw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
```

and found out:

```
$ nm /lib/libxml2.so.2 | grep __xmlStructuredErrorContext
000a99e8 t __xmlStructuredErrorContext
```

this makes me sick. there is a symbol there why it just can't link? do i lack of something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. this question is from long time ago. i found out why is that:

notice:

```
$ nm /lib/libxml2.so.2 | grep __xmlStructuredErrorContext
000a99e8 t __xmlStructuredErrorContext
```

this symbol has attribute of `t`, which is local, which won't be exported. it happens because the library is tooooooooo old.

but unfortunately, if you are working on `solaris` system, if you try to update `libxml2` by compiling it from source, it will fail, because of bug in either compiler or source. further reference in: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.lib.xslt/month=20110201

actually there is a short cut to install `lxml` with pre-compiled package using `openCSW`:

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i python27 py_lxml
```

it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Python3 on Solaris Sparc (5.11). OpenCSW version of lxml is for Python 2 only, so had to do the following:

- Get libxml2 and libz1 from OpenCSW (in my case these were libz1-1.2.8,REV=2013.09.23-SunOS5.10-sparc-CSW and libxml2_2-2.9.3,REV=2016.02.16-SunOS5.10-sparc-CSW, downloaded from openCSW: https://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/)
- Extract corresponding SO files (not sparcv9 versions) from these packages
- Create symlinks

> ```
> libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.9.3
> libxml2.so.2.9.3
> libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
> libz.so.1.2.8
> ```

- Add path to this folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in your .bashrc