# "undefined symbol: __xmlStructuredErrorContext" importing etree from lxml

Tags: python, lxml, libxml2, importerror, libxslt

```
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: __xmlStructuredErrorContext
```

i do have libxml2 and libxslt, i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling too, it didn't help.
lxml version: 3.4.4,
python: 3.4.2,
OS: RHEL 5.5
Please help resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: It's not just a matter of having them, you have to have the same versions that the shared library was compiled against.

Comment: BTW, even though the answer given by Regis doesn't fix your immediate problem here, it *is* the better practice to use (as it imports the `etree` module directly, rather than importing the `lxml` module and then resolving its `etree` reference).

Comment: BTW, you might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488797/failed-to-linked-symbol-in-so-file-while-the-symbol-exists to be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of `lxml.etree` was compiled against a different version of `libxml2` than the one you have actually installed. Reinstalling libxml2 doesn't help because you're just reinstalling the same code. Reinstalling the binaries that bundle your existing `etree.cpython-34m.so` binary won't work either, because that binary itself is inherently broken ([it refers to a symbol that isn't exported in all versions of libxml2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488797/failed-to-linked-symbol-in-so-file-while-the-symbol-exists)).

Uninstall the Python module -- not the C library -- and reinstall it *from source*. (`pip` should be able to do this automatically, assuming that you have -devel headers for libxml2 and libxslt installed and an appropriate compiler).

Comment: Thanks Charles, but i did install lxml using pip. and how do i see how the shared library was compiled against?

Comment: You might use `ldd` to look up the libxml2 library used by the .so file in question (making sure there's no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in the environment when your code is invoked at runtime overriding with a different location), and `nm` to look at the symbols it contains.

Comment: Thanks Charles, i went through the link and i did the same and here is my error 
`[root@qos-ucs1 lib]# nm libxml2.so.2 | grep __xmlStructuredErrorContext
00000000000a2750 T __xmlStructuredErrorContext`

Comment: and i do have a 'T', i am not sure if that is causing the same error

Comment: Okay -- so your copy of libxml2 in `/usr/lib` **does** export that symbol, so it should work fine. Maybe you have another copy somewhere else? Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD in your runtime environment to see if they're causing different libraries to be used.

Comment: You might also use `strace` to see which files are being loaded at runtime.