# lxml xpath cannot import name etree

Tags: python, lxml

Using Ubuntu 14.04 following this lxml xpath tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgWfF-Ut0zM

Updated with this to download pip's upstream version of lxml
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089634

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install -U lxml
python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> page = open('/root/page1.html').read()
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name etree
```

Comment: Do you have an `lxml.py` in the local directory or maybe some corrupted install somewhere in your PYTHONPATH? `print lxml.__file__` and see if its the lxml you think it is. It should be `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: ...or maybe `site-packages`

Comment: Neither of these apply to me. What seems to work is `easy_install lxml`

Answer (score 4):

Installing another version of lxml solved my issue:

```
pip install lxml==3.6.0
```

Comment: On Windows Python 3.6.5 updating lxml to latest version via pip fixed this for me.